# Seeing for a ms pictures in slider

Tags: jquery, css, slider

everyone. 
I'm facing a problem with my slider. It works flawlessly, but the moment I refresh page, I can see for a ms all images that are in my slider before they disappear. Is there a way to make sure that on refresh, they wont be seen?

[Bootply example][1]

*(In this example it's okay, but on my real page, there is bigger delay)*

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-7">

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <a href="#" class="control_next">&gt;&gt;</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div id="slider">
        <ul>
          <li>SLIDE 1</li>
          <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
          <li>SLIDE 3</li>
          <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
        </ul>  
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <a href="#" class="control_prev">&lt;</a>
    </div>


  </div>

  <div class="col-md-5">
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

```
.container{
    background-color: green;
    width: 1380px;
}

#slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#slider ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#slider ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
}



a.control_prev, a.control_next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  padding: 4% 3%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.control_prev:hover, a.control_next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

a.control_prev {
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}

a.control_next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself.

I set css property *display:none* to all slider images at start, except the one I want to see first, and when slider arrow left/right is pressed, I just change display values to inline(using jquery) (all li child elements in my case).